# Likelihood function to compare two binomial variables

Tags: mathematical-statistics, maximum-likelihood, binomial-distribution, proportion, likelihood

I'm starting studying maximum likelihood estimation, and I have came across to a problem that I don't know how to solve yet.

How can I write the likelihood function to test the hypothesis that some treatment reduced the proportion of something bad to happen when compared to a control group? I understand I am dealing with two binomial distributions, but I can't think on how to write the likelihood.

If I had, for instance, this data:

\begin{tabular}{c|cc|c}
            & Control & Treatment & Total
Bad    &     51        &        12           &   63 
Good &   595       &       611          & 1206 
Total  &   646      &      623         &  1269
\end{tabular}

$p_C = .0789 $ and $p_T = .0192$

How do I write a likelihood to compare these two numbers? If I wanted to find the MLE of $p_C$ and $p_T$ analytically how should I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You just write down your model! If the sampling are independent in the treatment and control groups, you just have a product of two independent binomial likelihood!